# Serializer for collection of Avro objects

Tags: kotlin, serialization, apache-kafka, avro

I am trying to implement a cache that bases itself on [KCache](https://github.com/rayokota/kcache). The code below works, but I want to change the cache `value` to a `list` of `MyAvroObject`.

```
class Cache() {

    private val cache: KafkaCache<String, MyAvroObject>

    init {
        val cacheProps = Properties()
        cacheProps[KafkaCacheConfig.KAFKACACHE_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG] =
            appConfig.propertyOrNull("kafka.bootstrapServers")?.getString()
        cacheProps[KafkaCacheConfig.KAFKACACHE_GROUP_ID_CONFIG] =
            appConfig.propertyOrNull("applicationId")?.getString()
        cacheProps[KafkaCacheConfig.KAFKACACHE_CLIENT_ID_CONFIG] = "GeneratingUnitsCache"

        val serdeConfig = Collections.singletonMap(
            AbstractKafkaSchemaSerDeConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG,
            appConfig.property("kafka.schemaRegistryUrl").getString(),
        )

        val avroSerdes: Serde<MyAvroObject> = SpecificAvroSerde()
        avroSerdes.configure(serdeConfig, false)

        val test = Serdes.serdeFrom(mutableListOf<MyAvroObject>()::class.java)


        cache = KafkaCache(
            KafkaCacheConfig(cacheProps),
            Serdes.String(),
            avroSerdes
        )

        cache.init()
    }
    
    // Further class implementation

}
```

That is, I want

```
private val cache: KafkaCache<String, List<MyAvroObject>>
```

Is there an easy way to create a `Serdes` object for this "new" Avro object? The `test` value was my futile attempt at creating a `Serdes` object.

Comment: You could make a new Avro type that holds an array of `MyAvroObject`, but are you getting a specific error?

Comment: If I just change the definition of the cache to the line stated above, I get a type mismatch when constructing the cache. If I then use the `test` variable as the cache value serdes when constructing, I get a type mismatch when inserting lists of `MyAvroObject. 

Do you have an example of how I could create the new Avro type?

Comment: In AVDL, `record MyAvroObject {} record Container { array<MyAvroObject> data;}`